# How to bind to radio buttons created dynamically in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, radio-button

I'm using WPF and MVVM in an application I'm working on.

I was creating 5 radio buttons dynamically and at the time of creation I was setting the binding using an enumeration and an IValueConverter.

This was okay because I knew I only needed 5 radio buttons, but now the number of radio buttons that I need to create can change, they could be 5 as they could be 30.

So, which is the best way to bind the radio buttons with the code? I think I can't not use an enumeration any more, unless somehow I manage to create the enumeration dynamically, which I don't know if it is possible for what I've read about dynamic enumerations...

Thanks.

**Edit**

Here it is, more or less, the code I'm using to create the radio buttons dynamically.

```
public enum MappingOptions {
        Option0,
        Option1,
        Option2,
        Option3,
        Option4
    }

private MappingOptions mappingProperty;
public MappingOptions MappingProperty
{
    get { return mappingProperty; }
    set 
    {

        mappingProperty= value;
        base.RaisePropertyChanged("MappingProperty");

    }
}

private void CreateRadioButtons()
{
    int limit = 5;
    int count = 0;
    string groupName = "groupName";

    parent.FormWithRadioButtons.Children.Clear();
    foreach (CustomValue value in AllCustomValues)
    {
        if (count < limit)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton tmpRadioBtn = new System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton();
            tmpRadioBtn.DataContext = this;
            tmpRadioBtn.Content = value.Name;
            tmpRadioBtn.GroupName = groupName;
            tmpRadioBtn.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(10, 0, 0, 5);
            string parameter = string.format("Option{0}", count.ToString());

            System.Windows.Data.Binding tmpBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("MappingProperty");
            tmpBinding.Converter = new EnumBooleanConverter();
            tmpBinding.ConverterParameter = parameter;
            tmpBinding.Source = this;
            try
            {
                tmpRadioBtn.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, tmpBinding);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handle exeption
            }

            parent.FormWithRadioButtons.Children.Add(tmpRadioBtn);
            count += 1;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    MappingProperty = MappingOptions.Option0;
}

public class EnumBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string parameterString = parameter as string;
        if (parameterString == null)
            return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

         if (Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value) == false)
            return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

         object parameterValue = Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), parameterString);

         return parameterValue.Equals(value);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string parameterString = parameter as string;

        if (parameterString == null)
            return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

         return Enum.Parse(targetType, parameterString);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can get an idea of what you are binding to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a class that exposes string `Text` and boolean `IsChecked` properties and that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Call it, oh, `MutexViewModel`.

Create another class that implements an observable collection of these objects called `Mutexes`, and that handles `PropertyChanged` on each - e.g. has a constructor like:

```
public MutexesViewModel(IEnumerable<MutexViewModel> mutexes)
{
   _Mutexes = new ObservableCollection<MutexViewModel>();
   foreach (MutexViewModel m in Mutexes)
   {
      _Mutexes.Add(m);
      m.PropertyChanged += MutexViewModel_PropertyChanged;
   }
}
```

and an event handler that ensures that only one of the child objects has `IsChecked` set to true at any given time:

```
private void MutexViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   MutexViewModel m = (MutexViewModel)sender;
   if (e.PropertyName != "IsChecked" || !m.IsChecked)
   {
     return;
   }
   foreach (MutexViewModel other in _Mutexes.Where(x: x != m))
   {
      other.IsChecked = false;
   }
}
```

You now have a mechanism for creating an arbitrary number of named boolean properties that are all mutually exclusive, i.e. only one of them can be true at any given time.

Now create XAML like this - the `DataContext` for this is a `MutexesViewModel` object, but you can also bind the `ItemsSource` to something like `{DynamicResource myMutexesViewModel.Mutexes}`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Mutexes}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="local:MutexViewModel">
         <RadioButton Content="{Binding Text}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**Edit**

There was a syntax error in the XAML I posted, but nothing that should have ground you to a full stop.  These classes work:

```
public class MutexViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Text { get; set; }

    private bool _IsChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _IsChecked; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _IsChecked)
            {
                _IsChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler h = PropertyChanged;
        if (h != null)
        {
            h(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}

public class MutexesViewModel
{
    public MutexesViewModel(IEnumerable<MutexViewModel>mutexes)
    {
        Mutexes = new ObservableCollection<MutexViewModel>(mutexes);
        foreach (var m in Mutexes)
        {
            m.PropertyChanged += MutexViewModel_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

    private void MutexViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MutexViewModel m = (MutexViewModel) sender;
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsChecked" && m.IsChecked)
        {
            foreach(var other in Mutexes.Where(x => x != m))
            {
                other.IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MutexViewModel> Mutexes { get; set; }

}
```

Create a project, add those classes, paste the `ItemsControl` XAML into the main window's XAML, and add this to the code-behind of the main window:

```
    public enum Test
    {
        Foo,
        Bar,
        Baz,
        Bat
    } ;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var mutexes = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
            .Select(x => new MutexViewModel 
               { Text = Enum.GetName(typeof (Test), x) });

        DataContext = new MutexesViewModel(mutexes);
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer, but I don't think I can use this to solve my problem, cause I need to create the radio button from code and not from XAML, I tried using the classes you suggested and combining that with the code I posted above but it didn't worked...

Comment: There's absolutely no need to create these radio buttons from code.  See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know why it didn't worked the first time I tried, but today when I tried again it worked like a charm!